# SQL join between table rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, outer-join

I have an issue with sql query which to me seems pretty simple but can't get it to work properly.

So I have this table:

[image]
broadcast_media_id tells me if the data is 1 - email or 2 - phone. I need to gather both email and phone for one employee (with the same employee_id).

The query I tried is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ed.employee_id,
    ed.text_value AS email,
    x.text_value AS phone
FROM employee_data ed
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT employee_id,
                text_value
            FROM employee_data
            WHERE broadcast_media_id = 2
        ) x ON x.employee_id = ed.employee_id
WHERE broadcast_media_id = 1
```

Unfortunately because of the WHERE clause I get values only if employee has an email. So the result is this:

[image]

I am missing the phone value of "A773B230-754C-423F-97C4-E331268EA3C8" just because he doesn't have an email. I want to show this row as well and the value for email to be NULL.

It seems simple to me but I can't get it figured out.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: use `left join` then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a `join`, you can use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT ed.employee_id, ede.text_value AS email,
       edp.text_value AS phone
FROM employees e LEFT JOIN
     employee_data ede
     ON ede.employee_id = e.employee_id AND
        ede.broadcast_media_id = 1 LEFT JOIN
     employee_data edp
     ON edp.employee_id = e.employee_id AND
        edp.broadcast_media_id = 2
```

Note:  This assumes that you have an `employees` table -- which seems very reasonable.  This is quite handy for the `LEFT JOIN`.  This would probably have the best performance.

If you don't have an `employees` table, then use a subquery `(SELECT DISTINCT employee_id FROM employee_data)`.

I would tend to do this using conditional aggregation, which should also have reasonable performance.

Comment: I have employee table yes but I don't want to get it involve.
This seemed to work:

SELECT DISTINCT ed.employee_id, ede.text_value AS email, edp.text_value AS phone
FROM employee_data ed
LEFT JOIN employee_data ede ON ede.employee_id = ed.employee_id AND ede.broadcast_media_id = 1 
LEFT JOIN employee_data edp ON edp.employee_id = ed.employee_id AND edp.broadcast_media_id = 2

Thank you

Comment: @IvanBinev . . . If you care about performance, then the employee table is going to be much more efficient.

Comment: Well I do but left join won't do, because employee might not have phone and email and I don't want to show employees without any of them.

Answer (score 1):

Just use LEFT JOIN if the employee always have phone.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ed.employee_id,
    ed.text_value AS email,
    x.text_value AS phone
FROM employee_data ed
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT employee_id,
                text_value
            FROM employee_data
            WHERE broadcast_media_id = 2
        ) x ON x.employee_id = ed.employee_id
WHERE broadcast_media_id = 1
```

you can also avoid self join, but most probably the performance will be worse

```
SELECT ed.employee_id,
        MIN(CASE WHEN broadcast_media_id = 1 THEN text_value END) AS phone,
        MIN(CASE WHEN broadcast_media_id = 2 THEN text_value END) AS email
FROM employee_data ed
GROUP BY ed.employee_id
```

if employee can be without phone then you can use FULL JOIN

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    COALESCE(ed.employee_id, x.employee_id) employee_id,
    ed.text_value AS email,
    x.text_value AS phone
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM employee_data WHERE broadcast_media_id = 1) ed
    FULL JOIN (SELECT * FROM employee_data WHERE broadcast_media_id = 2) x
        ON x.employee_id = ed.employee_id;
```

Comment: the employee can have no phone or/and have no email.
I tried FULL JOIN but it gives me the same result only two row (because of the 'WHERE broadcast_media_id = 1' which removes the rows from other join).

The second query you've suggested works right. 
Why do you say the performance would be worse?

Comment: Thank you for the answer the MIN answer worked but I accepted another answer without the aggregate functions. This is really good alternative and is definitely useful!

Comment: added FULL JOIN example

Answer (score 1):

Try this query -- I didn't use any joins though

```
Select
    EmpID,
    Max(Case When MediaID = 1 Then TextValue End) As EmailID,
    Sum(Case When MediaID = 2 Then Cast(TextValue As Int) End) As PhoneNumber
From employee_data
Group By EmpID
Order By EmpID;
```

Here - Cost of Sorting = 78% And Table Scan = 22%.
(My instance data, it will definitely vary with your system and data though.)

If you do some indexing then it will perform better.

Answer (score 0):

i would use a double LEFT JOIN like:

```
    SELECT ed.employee_id
          ,COALESCE(ed1.text_value,'') as mail
          ,COALESCE(ed2.text_value,'') as phone
      FROM employee_data ed
 LEFT JOIN employee_data ed1
        ON ed.employee_id = ed1.employee_id
       AND ed1.broadcast_media_id = 1
 LEFT JOIN employee_data ed2
        ON ed.employee_id = ed2.employee_id
       AND ed2.broadcast_media_id = 2
```